# Getting Extra Duplicate values

Tags: sql, oracle

My requirement is this:

I have to find out the duplicates from the table PSPROJECTITEM, for the PROJECTNAME which is passed in the query. The objective is to find out the duplicate projects, which arises, when there is a back up created or during migrations. The duplicacy of rows have to checked between two projects, and if they have similar objects, like objecttype, objectid1, etc,and also, the count of these objects matches, then they are duplicates.

My problem is that the query which I have written picks up additional duplicates.

```
SELECT a.PROJECTNAME 
 , a.OBJECTTYPE 
 , a.OBJECTID1 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE1 
 , a.OBJECTID2 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE2 
 , a.OBJECTID3 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE3 
 , a.OBJECTID4 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE4,
 COUNT(*) as duplicate
  FROM PSPROJECTITEM a 
 WHERE a.projectname <> 'AZ_11' and
       exists ( 
 SELECT *
  FROM PSPROJECTITEM c 
 WHERE c.projectname  = 'AZ_11' 
   and a.objecttype = c.objecttype 
   AND a.objectid1 =c.objectid1 
   AND a.objectvalue1 = c.objectvalue1 
   AND a.objectid2 = c.objectid2 
   AND a.objectvalue2 = c.objectvalue2 
   AND a.objectid3 = c.objectid3 
   AND a.objectvalue3 = c.objectvalue3 
   AND a.objectid4 = c.objectid4 
   AND a.objectvalue4 = c.objectvalue4) 
   group by a.PROJECTNAME 
 , a.OBJECTTYPE 
 , a.OBJECTID1 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE1 
 , a.OBJECTID2 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE2 
 , a.OBJECTID3 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE3 
 , a.OBJECTID4 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE4
  ORDER BY a.projectname
```

The matching has to be done on the basis of the objects, and duplicate is the one which have same objects as well as the count of the objects also matches.

The duplicate for the projectname in the record PSPROJECTITEM is

```
A_RP    7   10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 0       0    
A_RP    46  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 12  PostBuild   0    
A_RP    46  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 12  PreBuild    0    
A_RP    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_ACCEPTED       FieldChange
A_RP    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_ACCPTRQST_LINK FieldChange
A_RP    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_ADD_PEER       FieldChange
A_RP    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_ALL_REQUESTS   FieldChange
A_RP    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_COMPLETED      FieldChange
A_RP    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DASH_RTNXFR_OK FieldChange
A_RP    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DECLINED       FieldChange
A_RP    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DELETE_ROW     FieldChange
A_RP    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DELETE_ROW2    FieldChange
A_RP    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DEL_NO         FieldChange
```

The query also fetches these values:

```
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    7   10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 0       0    
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    46  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 12  PostBuild   0    
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    46  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 12  PreBuild    0    
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_ACCEPTED       FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_ADD_PEER       FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_COMPLETED      FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DECLINED       FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DELETE_ROW     FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DELETE_ROW2    FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DEL_NO         FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DEL_YES        FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DRILLDOWN_BTN  FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DRILLTOP_BTN   FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DRILLUP_BTN    FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_EERVW_ACTION   FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_EP_ACCEPT      FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_EP_DECLINE     FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_EP_FDBCK_LINK  FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_EP_OLD_RVW_LINKFieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_GOALS_ACTION   FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_MANAGE_FDBCK   FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_MGRRVW_ACTION  FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_NOMINATED      FieldChange
AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD    48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_NOTIFY_PB      FieldChange
```

Means, these are additional value, and apart from these, extra values are like this.

Kindly help me in makthing this query perfect in order to fetch the duplicate for the project which is being passed in the query.

Database in use is oracle.

This is the result of

```
select * from PSPROJECTITEM where PROJECTNAME = 'AZ_11';
```

column name:

```
PROJECTNAME OBJECTID1 OBJECTVALUE1 OBJECTID2 OBJECTVALUE2 OBJECTID3 OBJECTVALUE3 OBJECTID4 OBJECTVALUE4

AZ_11   7   10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 0       0    
AZ_11   46  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 12  PostBuild   0    
AZ_11   46  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 12  PreBuild    0    
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_ACCEPTED       FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_ACCPTRQST_LINK FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_ADD_PEER       FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_ALL_REQUESTS   FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_COMPLETED      FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DASH_RTNXFR_OK FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DECLINED       FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DELETE_ROW     FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DELETE_ROW2    FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DEL_NO         FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DEL_YES        FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DRILLDOWN_BTN  FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DRILLTOP_BTN   FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_DRILLUP_BTN    FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_EERVW_ACTION   FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_EP_ACCEPT      FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_EP_DASH_CANCEL FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_EP_DECLINE     FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_EP_FDBCK_LINK  FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_EP_OLD_RVW_LINKFieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_GIVEACCPT_FDBCKFieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_GIVE_FDBCK     FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_GL_CREATE_LINK FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_GL_CREATE_MGR  FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_GL_LIST_LINK   FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_GL_LIST_MGR    FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_GOALS_ACTION   FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_MANAGE_FDBCK   FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_MGRRVW_ACTION  FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_NOMINATED      FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_NOTIFY_PB      FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_PCS_LINK       FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_PENDING        FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_REQUEST_FDBCK  FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_REQUEST_FDBCKS FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_REVIEW_ACTION  FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_RQST_FDBCK     FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_TOTAL_REQUESTS FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_TRANSFER_LINK  FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_EP_DASH_WRK  2   AZ_UNSOLICITED    FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_FDBCK_WRK    2   AZ_ARCHIVE_FLG    FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_FDBCK_WRK    2   AZ_CANCEL         FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_FDBCK_WRK    2   AZ_FBFILTER       FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_FDBCK_WRK    2   AZ_FB_COMPL_LINK  FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_FDBCK_WRK    2   AZ_FB_RQST_LINK   FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_FDBCK_WRK    2   AZ_REWORK_PB      FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_FDBCK_WRK    2   AZ_SUBMIT_LINK    FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_FDBCK_WRK    2   RETURN_LINK       FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_FDBCK_WRK    2   SELECT_ALL        FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_FDBCK_WRK    2   TOGGLE1           FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_GOALS_WRK    2   AZ_CANCEL         FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_GOALS_WRK    2   AZ_COPY           FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_GOALS_WRK    2   AZ_COPY_LINK      FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_GOALS_WRK    2   AZ_EDIT_LINK      FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_GOALS_WRK    2   AZ_GL_CREATE_LINK FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_GOALS_WRK    2   AZ_GOAL_FILTER    FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_GOALS_WRK    2   AZ_GOAL_FILTER1   FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_GOALS_WRK    2   AZ_GOAL_FILTER2   FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_GOALS_WRK    2   AZ_GOAL_FILTER3   FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_GOALS_WRK    2   AZ_GOAL_FILTER4   FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   AZ_GOALS_WRK    2   AZ_SELECT_ALL     FieldChange
AZ_11   48  10  AZ_EP_DASHBOARD 39  GBL 1   DERIVED_PSS 2   SEARCH_BTN        FieldChange
```

Thanks for the help in advance, also, let me know if I have missed any information.

This is the query which is being used to test the duplicacy:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM
WHERE PROJECTNAME='AZ_11'
minus
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM
WHERE PROJECTNAME='A_RP') 
union all
( 
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM
WHERE PROJECTNAME='A_RP'
minus
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM
WHERE PROJECTNAME='AZ_11'
);
```

For this,it returns blank rows.

When i run with these values:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM
WHERE PROJECTNAME='AZ_11'
minus
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM
WHERE PROJECTNAME='AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD ') 
union all
( 
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM
WHERE PROJECTNAME='AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD '
minus
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM
WHERE PROJECTNAME='AZ_11'
);
```

This reutrns:

```
65
0
```

Which means, that these are not duplicate projects, as objects don't match.

Just help me to get through this, this is very complex and I am out of ideas.

Comment: You may receive more help if you can give us a simple, cut-down example which reveals the nature of your problem.

Comment: @WW. Thanks. My problem of statement is like this I have a table named PSPROJECTITEM. I need to find out the project which are duplicate of a project. These duplicate rows come in the table when a migration from another environment, or a back up is created. The case to find duplicate is to match the objects which are similar between two different project, i.e, the original one and the duplicate one and also, the count of the objects among them must be equal. For eg: AZ_11 is the original project, and AZ_RP is the duplicate one. Thanks.

Comment: Any help on this? Kindly let me know if i have missed anything. thanks

Comment: Why do you think there is extra values? It seems, that project 'AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD' is a duplicate of 'AZ_11' too, cause it satisfies the conditions for duplicates. Add the result of `SELECT * FROM PSPROJECTITEM WHERE PROJECTNAME = 'AZ_11'` to make sure

Comment: @Mikhail: I have added the data. Also, added the data which is being used to test the duplicacy. Let me know any other information you want. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the project counts as duplicate, then it has the same number of rows as the other project. Try adding this condition in the sub query, for exapmle, like that:

```
SELECT a.PROJECTNAME 
 , a.OBJECTTYPE 
 , a.OBJECTID1 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE1 
 , a.OBJECTID2 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE2 
 , a.OBJECTID3 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE3 
 , a.OBJECTID4 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE4,
 COUNT(*) as duplicate
  FROM PSPROJECTITEM a 
 WHERE a.projectname <> 'AZ_11' and
       exists ( 
 SELECT *
  FROM PSPROJECTITEM c 
 WHERE c.projectname  = 'AZ_11' 
   and a.objecttype = c.objecttype 
   AND a.objectid1 =c.objectid1 
   AND a.objectvalue1 = c.objectvalue1 
   AND a.objectid2 = c.objectid2 
   AND a.objectvalue2 = c.objectvalue2 
   AND a.objectid3 = c.objectid3 
   AND a.objectvalue3 = c.objectvalue3 
   AND a.objectid4 = c.objectid4 
   AND a.objectvalue4 = c.objectvalue4) 
   AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM d
   WHERE d.projectname = a.projectname) = 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM e
   WHERE e.projectname = 'AZ_11')
   group by a.PROJECTNAME 
 , a.OBJECTTYPE 
 , a.OBJECTID1 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE1 
 , a.OBJECTID2 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE2 
 , a.OBJECTID3 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE3 
 , a.OBJECTID4 
 , a.OBJECTVALUE4
  ORDER BY a.projectname
```

Also, i think, this query returns you this result, cause you have blank space at the end of the name of the project 'AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD ':

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM
WHERE PROJECTNAME='AZ_11'
minus
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM
WHERE PROJECTNAME='AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD ') 
union all
( 
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM
WHERE PROJECTNAME='AZ_ASH_DASHBOARD '
minus
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PSPROJECTITEM
WHERE PROJECTNAME='AZ_11'
);
```

Comment: Hi mikahil, you have provided me the correct query. Also, the test query retrieves the following result:  65,368, i had removed the spaces and then executed.

Comment: Perfect, tested for another value. Thanks a lot for the help. God bless you.